# Phonegap Download PDF from URL using File Transfer Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a problem with downloading a pdf from an external url and save it on the **android device**. So far I get these errors:

```
download error source http://bbg.co.tz/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CC008962_Tanzania-tax-briefing-transfer-pricing_18-11-15.pdf
index.js:227 download error target /Phone/Download
index.js:228 upload error code1
```

And here is my code:

```
function bbgDownload(bbgURL)
{
   var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
   var uri = encodeURI(bbgURL);
   fileURL='/Phone/Download'
   fileTransfer.download(
       uri,
       fileURL,
       function(entry) {
           console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
       },
       function(error) {
           console.log("download error source " + error.source);
           console.log("download error target " + error.target);
           console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
       },
       false,
       {
           headers: {
               "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
           }
       }
   );
   console.log("Please show this URL " + bbgURL);
}
```

Comment: Can you please check and post your `bbgURL` variable?

Comment: Hey @beat , bbgURL works , i have checked it already . Here is the URL : http://bbg.co.tz/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CC008962_Tanzania-tax-briefing-transfer-pricing_18-11-15.pdf

Comment: what about using this `fileURL = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Phone/Download'` ?

Comment: Hey , Thanks for your help but still that does not work ,  getting the same error...

Comment: Where do you initiate your `fileURL`variable, like `var fileURL;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Append a filename to your fileURL variable. This worked for me, for example:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://bbg.co.tz/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CC008962_Tanzania-tax-briefing-transfer-pricing_18-11-15.pdf");
var fileURL = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/mydir/myPdfFile.pdf";

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi Beat , Thanks for your help but still it doesn't work . quick question , in fileURL , is the myPDFFile.pdf suppose to be created from the uri ? and if yes , what is the absolute url of fileURL on my device ? I have manage to solve the pdf download using an alternative method which is  window.open(bbgURL, '_system', 'location=yes') but i would like to know using your way